# Severe: Parse error in application web.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, web.xml, saxparseexception

I am trying to teach myself Java, Java EE, and Tomcat pretty much all at once.
(Experienced C/Obj-C dev)

I was following a tutorial at YouTube at: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bd50C6XUnFw

I am running:

- Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
- JVM 1.7.0_45-b18
- Mac OS X 10.8.5 x86_64

The error I'm seeing is:

```
SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at jndi:/localhost/FirstServlet/WEB-INF/web.xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jndi:/localhost/FirstServlet/WEB-INF/web.xml; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 19; Error at (8, 19) : Can't convert argument: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2687)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2719)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1054)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
```

As shown in the video the web.xml (at path `/Library/Tomcat/webapps/firstservlet/WEB-INF`) is:

```xml
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>My FirstServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>FirstServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <url-pattern>/myfirstservlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The error indicates that the issue is a null it's hitting after the `</servlet-mapping>`

So my only assumption is that the tutorial on YouTube is missing something and I must be missing an argument. Suggestions strongly welcomed.

Comment: Did you compile the servlet with the servlet jar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're missing `<servlet-name>...</servlet-name>` in `<servlet-mapping>` section:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>My FirstServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myfirstservlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Have a look at [basic web.xml file](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/appdev/web.xml.txt)

Answer (score 1):

Between the element servlet-mapping the element servlet-name is missing

```
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>MyFirstServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/myfirstservlet</url-patter>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The servlet name is a kind of id which creates a relationship between url and the guven Servlet class.

Answer (score 0):

> Suggestions strongly welcomed.

1. Don't rely on a single tutorial as your sole source of information ...
2. These things are *specified*.  If you have doubts about the accuracy of a "secondary source" such as a dubious tutorial video, look at the specification.
3. If reading a specification is too difficult for you<sup>1</sup>, then look for a reliable tutorial; e.g. for Java-related stuff, look for one written by Oracle.

---

<sup>1 - People who label a specification "obtuse" are probably missing the real point of the specification.  A good specification is written with accuracy, precision and completeness as its primary goals.  A (so-called) specification that reads like a tutorial is most likely not meeting its primary goals properly.</sup>

---

In this case, the [Servlet spec 3.0](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf) (section 14.4.11) makes it clear that you need a `servlet-name` element to say what Servlet the matching requests are mapped to.

(You could most likely find the same information in other tutorials, etcetera ...)

Comment: Good information about tutorials, I am still searching for spec. That's a good link.

Comment: Google is often good way to find a specification.  In this case "servlet specification 3.0" found it (2nd hit), and "servlet specification" (without the version) found others.  In this particular case, the answer should be the same across all versions of the spec.

Comment: +1. btw the official [Java EE Documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/documentation/index.html) page has a section **Specifications**. The specification pages have the list of **ALL** the specifications that are included in the Java EE with the corresponding download links.  Also the OP may find it useful to take a look at this answer [Which Java EE approach is best for me](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20407849/814702).