# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException error on Tomcat server -SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

Currently I am learning Spring MVC, when I run the Application on Tomcat server Version 9 , a 404 error comes with following error stack trace **(Platform : Windows 10)**

***SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at [file:/C:/Users/kaust/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/springmvc/WEB-INF/web.xml]
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/kaust/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/springmvc/WEB-INF/web.xml; lineNumber: 14; columnNumber: 20; Error at line [14] column [20]: [Error converting [null] to type [java.lang.String]]***

The below warning opens up in a dialog box :
***org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.FeatureNotFoundException: Feature 'servlet-mapping' not found.***

**My web.xml file**

```
<web-app>
<display-name>Hello Spring MVC</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>dispatcher</servlet-mapping>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> </web-app>
```

Comment: The first is just a warning. Spring doesn't support tomcat 10 use tomcat 9.

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Comment: @OlafKock I removed the images and modified the question.

Comment: @M.Deinum I switched to version 9 and modified my question. warning is gone, but java.lang.IllegalArgumentException still there

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20821513/severe-parse-error-in-application-web-xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20821513/severe-parse-error-in-application-web-xml).Check if this helps

Comment: @Xtense Thanks it worked I missed the Servlet name in servlet mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<servlet-mapping>` should enclose `<servlet-name>...</servlet-name>` instead of `<servlet-mapping>` tag

Here is the correct code:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```